# Properly zipping a file

Tags: powershell

My code below zips files, however, I'm concern that I get the following after running my code. Just wondering if I'm zipping them incorrectly.

```
VERBOSE: The archive file path 'C:\Users\Desktop\FunctionOutputs\ErrorFiles\Dev\TestingAgain__11122019-122639' supplied to the DestinationPath patameter does not include .zip extension. Hence .zip is appended to the supplied Destina
tionPath path and the archive file would be created at 'C:\Users\Desktop\FunctionOutputs\ErrorFiles\Dev\TestingAgain__11122019-122639.zip'.
VERBOSE: Preparing to compress...
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "C:\Users\Desktop\FunctionInputs\logs".
```

```
function LogZipper{

Param (
        #[Parameter (Mandatory=$true)] [STRING] $region,
        [Parameter (Mandatory=$true)] [STRING] $env,
        [Parameter (Mandatory=$true)] [STRING] $server



        )


    #$Sourcefile = "C:\ControlFile.csv"

 #   $StartProperties = Import-Csv $SourceFile | Where-Object { ($_.Server_Name -eq $server)  -and ($_.Start_Flag -eq "1")} `
                                              #  | Select Server_Name, Service_Name, Install_Location 



    #foreach($line in $StartProperties){
     #  $Install_Location = [string]$line.'Install_Location'

    $LogPath = "C:\Desktop\FunctionInputs"+"\logs"
    $LogPath

    $NetApp = "C:\Desktop\FunctionOutputs\ErrorFiles\"+$env     
    $NetApp

    if(Test-Path -Path $LogPath) {
        $ZipFolder = "$NetApp\$($server)_$($ErrorCode)_$((Get-Date).ToString("MMddyyyy-HHmmss"))"

        Compress-Archive -Path $LogPath -DestinationPath $ZipFolder -CompressionLevel Optimal -Force -Verbose 

        Get-ChildItem $NetApp -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15))} | Remove-Item -Verbose
        }
        Write-Host ("Files from " + $server +" have been zipped")
        Write-Host ("Files older than 15 days have been deleted")

}
LogZipper
```

Comment: It appears that the only complaint from the log is that ".zip" isn't explicitly part of the $ZipFolder , and it already compensates for it.  You could append ".zip" at the end of line you define $ZipFolder if you wanted to be thorough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-DestinationPath` parameter of the `Compress-Archive` cmdlet expects the path to the output ZIP *file*, not a *directory*.

If you pass a path argument that doesn't end in `.zip` (i.e., if the path doesn't have extension `.zip`), `Compress-Archive` will automatically append `.zip` to it - that is what the first verbose message in your question is saying.

That is:

- Your code doesn't create a ZIP file *inside* the `$ZipFolder` folder, it create a `$ZipFolder.zip` file *alongside* the `$ZipFolder` folder.
- You must append the name of the desired output ZIP file your `$ZipFolder` argument in order to create it inside of `$ZipFolder`.

  - E.g., to create a `logs.zip` file in `$ZipFolder`:
    `-DestinationPath (Join-Path $ZipFolder logs)`
  - If you also want to avoid the verbose message re the path not ending in `.zip`:
    `-DestinationPath (Join-Path $ZipFolder logs.zip)`

Note: Directory `$ZipFolder` *must already exist* for this to work; therefore, create it on demand first, e.g. with:
`$null = New-Item -Type Directory -Force $ZipFolder`
(`-Force` ensures that no error occurs if the directory already exists).

Comment: @JessTorres: The error implies that directory `$ZipFolder` doesn't exist - you must create it first; pleas see my update.

Comment: @JessTorres: No, your current code _does_ create a ZIP file _with_ compressed files, but it doesn't create it _inside_ `$ZipFolder`, it creates it as a _file_ that is in the same folder as `$ZipFolder` itself; e.g., if `$ZipFolder` is `c:\archives`, you'll create file `c:\archives.zip`.

Comment: @JessTorres: Not a big deal, but note that my user name is `mklement0` not `mkelement0` (no `e` after the `k`).